# GLSL shader flickering

Tags: opengl, scheme, glsl

I'm not so sure from what this problem is arising, I never had much experience with shaders so it might be unrelated to the actual shader (most probably the problem isn't in the shader)

I have this result

[image]

Fragment shader

```
#version 120
void main(void) {
  gl_FragColor[0] = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor[1] = 0.0;
  gl_FragColor[2] = 0.0;
}
```

Vertex shader

```
#version 120
attribute vec2 coord2d;

void main(void) {
  gl_Position = vec4(coord2d, 0.0, 1.0);
}
```

My render function

```
(define (renderFunc)
  (gl:Clear gl:COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)

  (gl:UseProgram program)

  (gl:EnableVertexAttribArray attribute_coord2d)

  (gl:Begin gl:TRIANGLES)
    (gl:Vertex3f 0.0 0.8 0)
    (gl:Vertex3f -0.8 -0.8 0)
    (gl:Vertex3f 0.8 -0.8 0)
  (gl:End)

  (gl:DisableVertexAttribArray attribute_coord2d)

  (glut:SwapBuffers))
```

And my Init function

```
(define (initFunc)
  (gl:ClearColor 1 1 1 1)

  (gl:Enable gl:TEXTURE_2D)
  (gl:Enable gl:LIGHTING)

  (gl:Enable gl:BLEND)
  (gl:BlendFunc gl:SRC_ALPHA gl:ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

  (set! program (CreatePorgram (list
      (CreateShader gl:VERTEX_SHADER (LoadScript "vs.glsl"))
      (CreateShader gl:FRAGMENT_SHADER (LoadScript "vf.glsl")))))

  (set! attribute_coord2d (gl:GetAttribLocation program "coord2d"))

  (print "attribute_coord2d: " attribute_coord2d)
  (print "vbo_triangle: " vbo_triangle)
  (print "program: " program)

  (print (gl:GetError)))
```

Not sure exactly why but the shader gets loaded correctly and so on. `glGetError` doesn't return any error and everything seems to work fine.

I based my code on this tutorial which compile and work fine on my machine:

http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenGL_Programming/Modern_OpenGL_Introduction

I have the feeling that this error my be related to my scheme bindings. When a shader is binded into memory, can we free the source sent to opengl. I'm pretty sure that the source code for the shader gets freed once the shader is generated.

I'm pretty lost at finding what is different in my code, I heard about glUniform but I believe that in my case it shouldn't really matter much.

I used `glBegin` and `glEnd` because I had some problems creating VBOs. If vbos are a requirement, then I'll make sure it works first.

By the way, we should see a black triangle instead of a triangle of black dots.

Here is what it looks like when superposing a hundread triangles. The pixels that are rendered black aren't completely random. They actually form some sort of pattern while pixels that are still white are always white most of the time.

[image]

Comment: Are you using Chicken with the [allegro egg](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/allegro/) by any chance? It's hard to try to reproduce anything without knowing what Scheme implementation and libraries you're working with.

Comment: I'm using Chicken Scheme with a modified version of the Opengl egg, I can push it to github later today.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young in case you care, I added the project and my work on github https://github.com/llacroix/chicken-opengl-bindings and the other project is called purity. I'm mostly translating some tutorials in Scheme and I'm not really a schemer so that should look like the beginning of a long journey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could it be that gl_FragColor is a vec4, expecting an alpha value. Blending is enabled but uninitialized values are left as the fragment alpha value causing the flickering?

Does this fix it?

```
gl_FragColor = vec4(0,0,0,1);
```

The reason it flickers is to do with when threads (to execute the fragment shader) are scheduled. Threads wind up resident in memory where the alpha value location just happens to have data from a previous thing the GPU was doing.

Comment: Removing the blending or adding the alpha value fixed the problem.